# Does each queue consumer process need its own Docker image?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, queue, keda

In a Kubernetes cluster environment that interacts with many queues for processing background tasks. Do I need to create separate executables (and therefore Docker images) for each queue to be consumed?

Assuming, that I'm using KEDA to trigger the running of a Docker image defined as a Job.

We are moving from a WebJob/Azure Functions environment where multiple queue-consuming functions can exist in a single executable.

What is best practice?

Comment: Single executable packaged in single docker container can be executed multiple times using replica set. For `Kind: job` this might be useful https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/

Comment: It's not clear for me what the problem is

Comment: I've got 30+ fine grained queues. Do I need the overhead of building and deploying this many docker images? (CI will manage most of this but there becomes slot of moving parts.)

Answer (score 0):

It is common practise to have a high degree of separation of workloads in during execution when it comes to Kubernetes. Thus it would make sense that consumer is its own Deployment or Job. Since you already have multiple queues that are spearate it makes sense to also separate the consumers. For example if one consumer hands, or needs a restart or upgrade it can be done with no impact on other consumers.

It does not require you to have separate Docker images though. If all consumers are the same excpet some configuration values like endpoints. You can define and build one common image and pass in configuration through environment variables, configmaps or secrets.

In other words, during execution it is common to have the consumers separated, but they can still share the same image with differences just in configuration